# How do i find the smallest value in prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I have the following code

```
option(2):-
    write('Enter place of origin: '), read(Origin),
    write('Enter place of destination: '), read(Destination),
    path(Origin, Destination, Path, Length),nl,nl,
    printPath(Path), write(' '),
    writef(' TOTAL DISTANCE = %d', [Length]),nl,fail;true.
```

And I wanted to find the smallest value among the lengths. I get an output similar to this

```
bahirdar-->mota  TOTAL DISTANCE = 100
bahirdar-->markos-->mota  TOTAL DISTANCE = 70
```

Comment: in SWI, see library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)). Then you could `?- aggregate(min(L,Path), Origin^Destination^Path^path(Origin, Destination, Path, L), Length).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) library as CappelliC proposes will work if you want to find the smallest distance between any two places in your database (according to predicate path/4). If you want to find the shortest path that a user inputs into your program, you will need to store that information. A simple way is to `asserta` the user's answers:

```
:- dynamic user_path/2.

option(2):-
  write('Enter place of origin: '), read(Origin),
  write('Enter place of destination: '), read(Destination),
  path(Origin, Destination, Path, Length),
  asserta(user_path(Origin, Destination)),
  nl,nl,     
  printPath(Path), write(' '),
  writef(' TOTAL DISTANCE = %d', [Length]),nl,fail
 ;
  true.
```

Then you can find the minimum path with

```
min_path(Path) :- 
 aggregate(
           min(L,Path), 
           Origin^Destination^Path^(
            user_path(Origin, Destination),
            path(Origin, Destination, Path, L)
           ), 
           Length
          ).
```